# Spark and Scala, add new column with value from another dataframe by mapping common key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes.
df1 =

```
dep-code    rank
    abc        1
    bcd        2
```

df2 =

```
some cols...  dep-code 
                  abc
                  bcd
                  abc
```

I want to add new column to df2 as rank with df1.dep-code = df2.dep-code

result -

```
some cols...   dep-code   rank
                  abc       1
                  bcd       2
                  abc       1
```

Comment: just do `df2.join(df1, Seq("dep-code"), "left")` and you should be fine. But next time before you ask questions, do some research first as there are so many questions and answers regarding how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple join:

```
df2.join(df1, "dep-code")
```

With the following inpouts:

df1 with the join and the desired column:

```
+--------+----+
|dep-code|rank|
+--------+----+
|     abc|   1|
|     bcd|   2|
+--------+----+
```

df2 with the join column plus an extra one (`aColumn`):

```
+----------+--------+
|   aColumn|dep-code|
+----------+--------+
|      some|     abc|
| someother|     bcd|
|yetAnother|     abc|
+----------+--------+
```

You'll retrieve the output below:

```
+--------+----------+----+
|dep-code|   aColumn|rank|
+--------+----------+----+
|     abc|      some|   1|
|     abc|yetAnother|   1|
|     bcd| someother|   2|
+--------+----------+----+
```

Comment: this will remove rows from df2 if dep-code doesn't match.

Comment: right, op said he wants the results when df1.dep-code = df2.dep-code. So i assume it want a full join, not a left one.